# Is there a way to link to a Google+ comment?

Tags: google-plus

I cannot find anywhere on a Comment something I can just right-click and copy so I can have a direct link to it. Is there any way to link to a specific comment?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, no.

Comment: You can get a link to a whole post (from the text like "Yesterday 5:23 PM") but AFAIK not to an individual comment on a post.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to right-click and link to them yet, but there is an ID on the element you can use to build a link:

For example, https://plus.google.com/+FeliciaDay/posts/DKroN5F74Sy#z13jifpa0rnrzrpud23ky1h4wrvagfzxp04#1413850339753657

If you inspect the element, you can see that each comment is wrapped in a DIV tag with an ID attribute, which you can use to build a link. I'm sure it would be possible to build some kind of browser plugin or script that would let you create links to comments using this.

Comment: What a mess. This works (and is the best answer), *iff* you're on the post's individual page, and only if the floating toolbar is already displayed. I've had the page scroll to the `#` but then have everything after the `#` erase after the bar appears. Here's a link [to a specific post](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/aeJGSb7zheb#z13qgxf55zy2y34id04cipiaorjydfxg5tc0k#1425034256333065) that seems to reload as the floating bar is shown (FF 38.0.1).

Comment: And [here's it not working on the main page](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736#z13qgxf55zy2y34id04cipiaorjydfxg5tc0k#1424973194397577) unless the comment has already been exposed. That makes some sense, but it'd be nice if they had an API to make this cleaner.

Comment: Is this still accurate? I can see things like `commentid="z131hbdo4obmfhgh504cgvww2yv1vrm5j0g#1528137166749957"`, but no `id=` anywhere.